# Problem to get an element from an array , JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch-api

I'm learning JavaScript and got a problem when I want to fetch some information on the Pokemon API.
I can fetch some information but I want to get the second types of Pokemon, as you can see, it's working for the first type but not the second.

I think the problem is that not all the Pokemon has two types (`apiTypes`), but I don't know how to render the second one.

The JSON : https://pokebuildapi.fr/api/v1/pokemon

```
/ https://pokebuildapi.fr/api/v1/pokemon

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "pokedexId": 1,
    "name": "Bulbizarre",
    "image": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/1.png",
    "sprite": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1.png",
    "slug": "Bulbizarre",
    "stats": {
      "HP": 45,
      "attack": 49,
      "defense": 49,
      "special_attack": 65,
      "special_defense": 65,
      "speed": 45
    },
    "apiTypes": [
      {
        "name": "Poison",
        "image": "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemongo/images/0/05/Poison.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Plante",
        "image": "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemongo/images/c/c5/Grass.png"
      }
    ],
```

My actual code:
when I put `<img src="${pokemon.apiTypes[0].image}" id="type">`, it's rendering the first type.
but if I put `<img src="${pokemon.apiTypes[1].image}" id="type">`, it doesn't render the second one.

```
const pokemonContainer = document.querySelector('.pokemon-container')
let pokemonData = []

async function fetchPokemon(){
await fetch("https://pokebuildapi.fr/api/v1/pokemon")
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => pokemonData = data);

console.log(pokemonData);

pokemonDisplay()
};

function pokemonDisplay(){
    pokemonContainer.innerHTML = pokemonData
    .map((pokemon) => 
    
    `
    <div class="card">
    <h2>#${pokemon.id}  ${pokemon.name}</h2>
    <img src="${pokemon.image}" id="pic">
    <img src="${pokemon.apiTypes[0].image}" id="type">
    <ul>
    <li>PV  ${pokemon.stats.HP}</li>
    <li>Att  ${pokemon.stats.attack}</li>
    <li>Def  ${pokemon.stats.defense}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    `
    
    ).join("")};

window.addEventListener('load', fetchPokemon);
```

Comment: Do you get an error message regarding `pokemon.apiTypes[1].image`? `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')`?

Comment: Because you are mapping the pokemonData array which means you are changing/overwriting the existing array values. What you should do is iterate over array elements!

Comment: @jkalandarov What does it mean? Where is something overwritten?

Comment: IDs have to be unique. You can't have two elements with the same ID. Both image elements have the same ID in your code snippet.

Comment: The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. Doc here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @jkalandarov Yes, it creates an array with all the elements. And `join` concatenates them. Looks correct and the code works. Where does this overwrite something?

Comment: Have you tried adding `<img src="${pokemon.apiTypes[1].image}" id="type">`  after `<img src="${pokemon.apiTypes[0].image}" id="type">` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check whether `pokemon.apiTypes[1].image` exists:

```
const pokemonContainer = document.querySelector('.pokemon-container');
let pokemonData = [];

async function fetchPokemon(){
await fetch("https://pokebuildapi.fr/api/v1/pokemon")
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => pokemonData = data);

pokemonDisplay()
}

function pokemonDisplay(){
    pokemonContainer.innerHTML = pokemonData
    .map((pokemon) => 
    
    `
    <div class="card">
    <h2>#${pokemon.id}  ${pokemon.name}</h2>
    <img src="${pokemon.image}" class="pic">
    <img src="${pokemon.apiTypes[0].image}" class="type">` +
    (pokemon.apiTypes[1]?.image ? `<img src="${pokemon.apiTypes[1].image}" class="type">` : '') +
    `<ul>
    <li>PV  ${pokemon.stats.HP}</li>
    <li>Att  ${pokemon.stats.attack}</li>
    <li>Def  ${pokemon.stats.defense}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    `
    
    ).join("")};

window.addEventListener('load', fetchPokemon);
```

I also replaced all IDs with classes, because IDs have to be unique.